# The first speed calculated ball does not go to the target it should go

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, motion, projectile, kinematics

> In the function below, The distance between ball and target is
>   known(R). Also, the angle between the resultant vector and the x-axis is
>   known(LaunchAngle). Thanks to these parameters(R, LaunchAngle), I
>   calculate the initial velocity of a ball. I checked all the values.
>   According to physics, they are all correct. Although all calculations
>   are correct, the ball does not hit the target.

```
void LaunchFromTargetPositionWithoutFrictionForce()
        {
            Vector3 projectileXZPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0.0f, transform.position.z);
            Vector3 targetXZPos = new Vector3(TargetObjectTF.position.x, 0.0f, TargetObjectTF.position.z);
            transform.LookAt(targetXZPos);

            float R = Vector3.Distance(projectileXZPos, targetXZPos);
            float G = -Physics.gravity.y;

            float Vz = Mathf.Sqrt(G * R / Mathf.Sin((2.0f * LaunchAngle) * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
            float Vy = Vz * Mathf.Sin(LaunchAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
            float Vx = Vz * Mathf.Cos(LaunchAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
            text2.text = "vz: " + Vz.ToString() + " vy: " + Vy.ToString() + " vx: " + Vx.ToString();

            Vector3 localVelocity = new Vector3(0f, Vy, Vx);
            Vector3 globalVelocity = transform.TransformDirection(localVelocity);


            rigid.velocity = globalVelocity;
            bTargetReady = true;

            if (isSlowMotion) timeManager.slowMotion();
        }
```

First location of the ball
[image: first location of ball]

And after 2-dimensional motion it is hit before target
[image: 2d motion befor target hit]

Comment: maybe i understand it wrong, but it seems like the target is on course? does it stop befor the target? is there a collider that is to big?

Comment: according to the angle, sometimes it stops before the target, sometimes after the target, and sometimes stops on exact target. But it should stop on target every time. There is a collider.

Comment: does rigidbody using diffrent physics? According to the physic calculations it should hit target every time. But it hits somewhere else what i calculated??

Comment: What is the difference between stop points on axis ? Like sometimes it stops at 10.000134f and sometimes it stops at 10.000256f ? Numbers are just example but what I've experienced is dealing with precision is hard. Maybe try to fix the positions and numbers to .00f that might help

Comment: the difference is not small. It is like 10f and - 13f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed first 3 line  with below codes. And problem solved.

```
    Vector3 projectileXZPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 targetXZPos = TargetObjectTF.position;
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(projectileXZPos, targetXZPos);
    transform.LookAt(targetXZPos);
```